# Phonegap App using Application express database

Tags: oracle, web-services, cordova, mobile, oracle-apex

I'm about to make an application using phonegap but the database I have to use is already used by a web app made with oracle application express. So I wanted to know is there a way of creating a web service inside that web app to retrieve the data on my mobile app ?

The second option I was thinking about is not passing by the apex web app, but just trying to use a WS to access the oracle database (with all the problems I will have to face at deployment). Can someone give me some directives ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the RESTful services built into Apex - [Oracle Rest Data Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/documentation/listener-dev-guide-1979546.html) which could provide good integration with Phonegap. You'll need an up to date Apex Environment to use these.

Answer (score 0):

One quick google search will give you a couple of presentations [(1)](http://www.slideshare.net/christianrokitta5/native-app-with-apex-and-phone-gap) [(2)](http://www.slideshare.net/christianrokitta5/apex-phone-gap)

About integration between Apex and Phonegap, and a [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=FiPszRVwJ-AC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=oracle%20apex%20with%20phonegap%20frameworks&source=bl&ots=G4nOWoG9Ix&sig=qCJUbd0XCb8_xMCqM14kCG2LCMk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F7X4UtOBOYqZiAfvo4DQCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=oracle%20apex%20with%20phonegap%20frameworks&f=false)

Comment: I will dig with your links to see what I can have ! Thanks